# Ubuntu won't start properly after updating graphics driver

Tags: drivers, graphics

I recently tried to update my graphics driver. It then asked me to restart, which I did. After this however, I reach a black screen and am asked to enter my login and password. Upon doing this it says that I have successfully logged in or something and that's pretty much it. I can enter commands and stuff but I don't know how to reach the desktop. Please help me. :(

Comment: What graphic card do you have? What Ubuntu version?

Comment: How did you update your driver?

Answer (score 0):

Exact same issue here but all I get is a black screen, nothing else. I installed 12.04 LTS and drivers were offered in settings and Additional drivers. Used the recommended driver in a list of about 5. Could really use a hand, I've reinstalled 4 times. Not sure how to troubleshoot and enter "terminal" and edit stuff. Help! SOS!